# Blog site template missing from the New SharePoint Site creation page

Tags: 2007, site-template

At the portal level in SP 2007 (http://portal/) , I go to create a new Blog subsite (http://portal/blog/) by using the "Create -> Sites and Workspaces". When I got to make the "Blog" template selection, the only available template is the "Publishing Site" template.

Yet, when I go to do the same in any of my site collections, all the standard templates appear (blog, news, records center, etc).

Does anyone know how to make the default templates appear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

D'oh. Finally figured out why it wasn't showing up.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/7f7641de-495f-4688-a4a9-203c780bcea8

Under Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Page layouts and site templates you need to add the template. Not sure how come these were missing...